# Content disappearing using IE6 when inserted with jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I have been developing this web application using Seadragon and jQuery.  I made the whole development using Firefox and Chrome for testing so I knew I would have to tweak some styling because of IExplorer (mostly IE6).

You can see the latest version here: http://fibics.interplex.ca

I got it done, but I still have one more problem.  Under IExplorer 6, when you click on "Add View", sometimes the views disappear. Again, most of the time (not always) it is reappearing when the hint of buttons (add view, slide show or delete all) is shown.  I am using the jQuery plugins Tipsy to display the hint.  Anyway, I am out of resources and I don't know what to do to fix this intermittent problem.

Do anyone has a clue?  I thought it was linked to the `fadeIn()` function of jQuery, but I simply add the content to the DOM now, I skipped the `fadeIn()` portion (at least for IE6), but it did not fix my problem.

The preview image is a table of multiple images with their size different than their native side and this table is wrapped in a `<li>` element which is add to the list of view which is an `<ul>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "+ Views"? I do not see "Add View". If thats the case, have you tried tweaking #viewList or the parent .ui-corner-bottom?

Maybe adding a display: inline-block; might "wake" IE up?